# Access multi-dimensional array of multiple types from another class in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I am new to C# and have investigated without success. I come from programming in PHP and I have the following JSON:

```
{"data": [
    {  "iD":0 , "name":"woody", "a":4.0, "b": 3.5, "foo": [5,8] },
    {  "iD":1 , "name":"donald", "a":5.0, "b": 2.4, "foo": [4, 2] }
]}
```

What I need is to create something similar in C#, if possible in a separate class to be able to access the data in the correct way.
I tried to create a different array for each item but I think it is not correct.

From what I've researched, based on the JSON I've presented as an example, I have the following data types: "string, int and double".
In PHP you can mix this type of data in the same array and call it through indexes but I don't know exactly how to do the same in C #.

Eye, my question is not how to read the JSON that I have put above, but how to create an similar array (or an object) with that data structure and that I can access it from another class.

I hope I was clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create a class with three properties in it. The key-feature of a staically-typed language such as C# is, that you allways know the exact types you get when accessing a property. Thus when you write `dataObject.name` you get a string and can perform any string-operation, whereas if you would apply any math on that string you´d get a compiler-error. You should definitly read about the basic concepts of C#.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't have much experience in OOP. Could you give me an example of a class with that structure? I know another option is to create a JSON file and read it from C#. But for a learning topic I would like to know how to do it directly in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create classes/structs to represent this data's *structure*:

```
public class Datum {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public List<int> C { get; set; }
}
```

You can either store this `Datum` directly in a `List<Datum>`, or like you have done in the JSON, store it in another class as a property named `Data`:

```
public class RootObject {
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can create these objects using [object and collection initialisers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers):

```
var rootObject = new RootObject {
    Data = new List<Datum> {
        new Datum {
            ID = 0,
            Name = "Woody",
            A = 4.0,
            B = 3.5,
            C = new List<int> { 5, 8 }
        },
        new Datum {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the appropriate tests and it worked as expected, thanks for the info.